# Failed connection to localhost inside docker container in Gitlab CI with docker:dind

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, airflow, gitlab-ci

the requests call is :

```
res = requests.post(f"{API_BASE_URL}/dags/sql_data_transfer/dagRuns", headers={
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {TEST_TOKEN}'},

                    json={
                        "dag_run_id": dag_run_id,
                        'conf': conf
                    }
                    )
```

This works locally but in gitlab it fails using `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `docker` as host.

The error:

```
            if isinstance(e.reason, _ProxyError):
                raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    
            if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
                # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
                raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    
>           raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
E           requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/dags/sql_data_transfer/dagRuns (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8e98491bd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:519: ConnectionError
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '2.2'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: airflow
  build: airflow
  environment:
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor #
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION=True
    - AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO


  volumes:
    - ./airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./airflow/airflow-data/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./airflow/airflow-data/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./airflow/config/airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    - postgres

services:
  airflow-observer:
    << : *airflow-common
    container_name: airflow_observer
    command: airflow webserver
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
```

Comment: can you update the question and add .yml file?

Comment: @George ymladded

Comment: If you are making the request from another container you need to use `airflow_observer:8080` as `localhost` refers to the container itself. If you are making the request from gitlabci/host then you need to use port `8082` as your `ports` specification says that the host port is `8082`

Comment: I am calling from container itself, I even tried ping: nc: connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

Comment: this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/7004653